Need help in xslt 2.0 for excluding special charactcers
I am using this code
<xsl:value-of select="
  translate(
    wd:CF_LRV_Primary_Address_Full_with_Country,
    translate(
      wd:CF_LRV_Primary_Address_Full_with_Country,
      'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
      ''),
    '')" />

The value  I am getting as

forestviewcirxaFranksvilleWIxaUnitedStatesofAmerica

Instead I should be getting as:

forest view cir Franks ville WI United States of America

I tried the above code
<xsl:value-of select="
  translate(
    wd:CF_LRV_Primary_Address_Full_with_Country,
    translate(
      wd:CF_LRV_Primary_Address_Full_with_Country,
      'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
      ''),
    '')" />

The value  I am getting as

forestviewcirxaFranksvilleWIxaUnitedStatesofAmerica

Instead I should be getting as:

forest view cir Franks ville WI United States of America


So what is the original input string? And which (special) characters do you need to remove? XSLT 2 has a replace method that is often easier to use than translate. But currently it is not clear how your input string looks and which characters you want to remove.

Hi Martin, I just wanted to remove : xa " from the value I am getting ForestviewcirxaFranksvilleWIxaUnitedStatesofAmerica. And I also I have tried with using replace but still has the same issue.

Hi Martin, I just wanted to remove : xa " from the value I am getting ForestviewcirxaFranksvilleWIxaUnitedStatesofAmerica. And I also I have tried with using replace but still has the same issue. I tried using the below one but still getting same issue <xsl:value-of select="translate(wd:CF_LRV_Primary_Address_Full_with_Country,'xa','')"/>

Please edit your question and try to format the input and output strings with backticks so that we can read them clearly. Also if you want to remove the letters xa from the value in wd:CF_LRV_Primary_Address_Full_with_Country then translate(wd:CF_LRV_Primary_Address_Full_with_Country,'xa','') should achieve that but you haven't shown is the relevant XML input sample or at least that element in a clean and clearly formatted way.
